# Gmail Api Billing method

Tags: smtp, google-workspace

I will be using the Gmail API for sending mails from my website with my submail (a noreply-mail),  I have added a billing method for the admin mail but not for my sub mails, is that something I have to do so it works correctly? (thinking about the credits and so on?)

Very thankful for your help!

/Dejan

Answer (score 0):

Gmail API is not a billed service, but do be mindful of quota limits:

- [Gmail sending limits in Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)
- [Gmail API usage limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota)

The more restrictive of the above limits will apply.